# How to stay open the rad menu after clicking it?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, telerik, radmenu

Code:

```
<telerik:RadMenuItem x:Name="radMenuHome">
</telerik:RadMenuItem>
```

How to stay open the rad menu after clicking it in **wpf**? It should behave like the way as displayed in the following [url](http://www.sitefinity.com/clientsfiles/231104_radmenu.png?sfvrsn=0). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try set `StaysOpenOnClick` to *`True`*, by default it is `False`:

```
<telerik:RadMenuItem x:Name="radMenuHome"
                     Header="Menu"
                     StaysOpenOnClick="True" ...>
```

Comment: I tried `StaysOpenOnClick`, but even though the menu gets `hidden` after clicking on it. I am getting a popup dialog after clicking on a menu, but the menu is hidden immediately after clicking on it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Try with this :**

- You should better use RadTabStrip control.
- The RadMenu does not support expand/collapse functionality you are
  looking for.  You can prevent collapsing of the item through
  `OnClientItemClosing event` , but you cannot detect the opened items
  and then collapse them.
- You can try to hack the menu by using `get_openedItem()` client side
  function and then check the item level by `get_level();`
- If the hovered item is level one and it is currently opened you can
  call `.close()` function that should collapse it.

**As for the selected items you can use the specific css file selectors : refer the link below**

[CSS Skin File Selectors](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip-appearance-css-selectors.html)

Comment: The question is about `WPF` and not related with `ASP.Net Ajax`. Thanks.